# Upload excel file from Databricks DBFS to SharePoint

Tags: python, azure, rest, sharepoint, databricks

How can I upload a file from Databricks DBFS to SharePoint using the library **requests** or any built-in library for REST API requests?

I found solutions on using **Office365-REST-Python-Client** but I don't want to use 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, we cannot upload files directly from Databricks DBFS to SharePoint. I recommend you use the following Rest API to upload file to SharePoint:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{list_title}')/rootfolder/files/add
```

More information for reference: [Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery)